# Службе WebHost не удалось обработать запрос

Tags: c#, mvc, wcf, iis, config

Имеется информационная система которая состоит из нескольких частей: MVC, WCF и прикрученный к ним thinktecture. Пытаюсь настроить авторизацию через Claims, от нескольких ошибок уже сумел исправиться, а вот от этой пока нет:

> Службе WebHost не удалось обработать запрос
>    Сведения об отправителе: System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment+HostingManager/24388906
>    Исключение: System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException: Не удается активировать службу "/issue/wstrust" из-за возникновения исключения в процессе компиляции.  Сообщение об исключении: Служба "System.ServiceModel.Security.WSTrustServiceContract" не имеет конечных точек приложения (не инфраструктурных). Это может быть связано с тем, что для данного приложения не найден файл конфигурации или в файле конфигурации не удалось найти элементы службы, соответствующие данному имени службы, или конечные точки не были определены в элементе службы.. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Служба "System.ServiceModel.Security.WSTrustServiceContract" не имеет конечных точек приложения (не инфраструктурных). Это может быть связано с тем, что для данного приложения не найден файл конфигурации или в файле конфигурации не удалось найти элементы службы, соответствующие данному имени службы, или конечные точки не были определены в элементе службы.
>      в System.ServiceModel.Description.DispatcherBuilder.EnsureThereAreApplicationEndpoints(ServiceDescription description)
>      в System.ServiceModel.Description.DispatcherBuilder.InitializeServiceHost(ServiceDescription description, ServiceHostBase serviceHost)
>      в System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.InitializeRuntime()
>      в System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
>      в System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
>      в System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.ActivateService(ServiceActivationInfo serviceActivationInfo, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)
>      в System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)
>      --- Конец трассировки внутреннего стека исключений ---
>      в System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)
>      в System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.EnsureServiceAvailableFast(String relativeVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)
>    Имя процесса: w3wp
>    ИД процесса: 31392

Читал статьи, в которых встречал про то, что в конфиге должен присутсвовать тэг с описанными привязками и поведением:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <ws2007FederationHttpBinding>
    <binding name="WS2007FederationHttpBinding_IClaimsService">
      <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
        <message establishSecurityContext="false" issuedKeyType="BearerKey">
          <issuer address="https://______/issue/wstrust/mixed/username"
            binding="ws2007HttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="https://______/issue/wstrust/mixed/username" />
          <issuerMetadata address="https://______/issue/wstrust/mex" />
          <tokenRequestParameters>
            <trust:SecondaryParameters xmlns:trust="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512">
              <trust:KeyType xmlns:trust="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512">http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/Bearer</trust:KeyType>
              <trust:CanonicalizationAlgorithm xmlns:trust="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512">http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#</trust:CanonicalizationAlgorithm>
              <trust:EncryptionAlgorithm xmlns:trust="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512">http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes256-cbc</trust:EncryptionAlgorithm>
            </trust:SecondaryParameters>
          </tokenRequestParameters>
        </message>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </ws2007FederationHttpBinding>...</system.serviceModel>
```

Тэг у меня есть, описания тоже. Может есть у кого идеи по этому поводу, что с ошибкой-то? Эта ошибка валится в MVC или WCF? Или может быть эта ошибка в IIS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решением проблемы стала настройка Thinktecture. В протоколах выбрал WS-Trust, задействовал его и настроил его конфигурацию, отметив:

> 1. "Message Security Endpoints"
> 2. "Mixed Mode Security Endpoints"
> 3. "Federated Authentication"
> 4. "Identity Delegation".

При этом не задействовал

> "Client Certificates Authentication"